certbot on ubuntu 22.04 server running on AWS
I am setting up nextcloud to run on ubuntu server 22.04 on AWS EC2.  My domain is hosted on BlueHost infinitycliff.com  I have an A record pointing to the AWS public ip that has been set more than 48 hours ago

nextcloud.infinitycliff.com.  14400   A
18.118.30.103

my config file /etc/apache2/sites-available/nextcloud.infinitycliff.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud.infinitycliff.com
    ServerName nextcloud.infinitycliff.com
    ServerAlias nextcloud.infinitycliff.com

    <Directory "/var/www/nextcloud.infinitycliff.com/">
        Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>

   TransferLog /var/log/apache2/nextcloud.infinitycliff.com_access.log
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/nextcloud.infinitycliff.com_error.log

</VirtualHost>

port 80 and 443 are open in firewall
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)  

and via inbound rules in AWS
sgr-0d3a5d165a331302b
IPv4
Custom ICMP - IPv4
Echo Request
N/A
73.152.221.55/32
Allow ping from Home
–
sgr-
IPv4
HTTPS
TCP
443
73.152.221.55/32
–
–
sgr-
IPv4
SSH
TCP
22
73.152.221.55/32
SSH
–
sgr-
IPv4
HTTP
TCP
80
73.152.221.55/32
Port 80

running $  sudo certbot --apache returns:
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: nextcloud.infinitycliff.com
  Type:   connection
  Detail: 18.118.30.103: Fetching http://nextcloud.infinitycliff.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/j3mLW1Qg-kfvOotya4Q9wRO6Pm28WGXh4yEgpTTTR4Y: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.


going to nextcloud.infinitycliff.com opens the nextcloud webpage but shows Access through untrusted domain
Any help would be appreciated.

I think you've actually answered your question already..... within your question.
It looks like you've configured your AWS Security Group rules to only allow Inbound Port 80 Traffic from your Home IP Address.
The way that Certbot/Lets Encrypt works is that the ACME Challenge could come from anywhere, it doesn't come from your home IP Address.
Test updating your AWS Security Group Rules to allow Port 80 Traffic from Anywhere then this will probably work.
Another option if you don't want to use Certbot/Lets Encrypt at the Ubuntu level is that you can use AWS Certificate Manager to handle this for you, but that does then introduce an extra layer of infrastructure through an Application Load Balancer.
